# Undeploying hibernate-validator from Tomcat 7

Tags: maven, tomcat7, hibernate-validator, maven-cargo

I have a maven project.
With Spring 3 and Hibernate.

I using org.codehaus.cargo to deploy/redeploy the war file in my tomcat 7.

On initial start of tomcat this deploy works fine. But i can't undeploy the project from tomcat 7.
Everytime i try to undeploy it leaves /{project}/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.0.0.GA.jar

What can i do?

Thanks a lot
Valtos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are on Windows.  Sometimes JAR files can get locked because a URL resource remains open.

Try turning on `antiJarLocking and antiResourceLocking` (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) in your context file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737983/tomcat-6-whats-the-significance-of-antiresourcelocking-antijarlocking) discussion might also be relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I have googled for that problem a lot of time and found nothing in that direction.